# How to update specific row in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, react-native

I would like to update a specific table's row values but got no idea how could I do it.

So how the structure looks like:

db:
 jobs:
  job(I want to select where the jobID is the same as from the parameters)

```
export async function UpdateJobDetails(data) {
    const query = `
        UPDATE
            job
        SET
            Company = ?, 
            SubBuilding = ?, 
            BuildingName = ?, 
            BuildingNumber = ?,
            PrimaryStreet = ?, 
            SecondaryStreet = ?, 
            Town = ?, 
            County = ?, 
            Postcode = ?
        FROM
            db_jobs
        WHERE
            db_jobs.jobID = ?
    `
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let forms = []
        db.transaction((tx) => {
            tx.executeSql(query, [data.Company, data.SubBuilding, data.BuildingName, data.BuildingNumber, data.PrimaryStreet, data.SecondaryStreet, data.Town, data.County, data.Postcode, data.dataJobID], (tx, results) => {
                resolve(forms)
            })
        })
    })
}
```

I know the code above is not good, I just think its help to understand my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of your `UPDATE` statement is wrong.
Remove
`FROM db_jobs` from the statement. It should be `UPDATE <table name> SET ...`
Replace `<table name>` with the actual table name.

Comment: what do you mean by this?

Comment: @IstvanOrban: he means that the `FROM db_jobs` is wrong here. The `Update` statement doesn't contain a `FROM`. It should be `UPDATE <table_name> SET ...`

Comment: @jps This is what exactly trying to say.Thanks buddy